# Module statistics has no attribute quantiles

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find quantiles of my dummy data with the help of the python statistics module but whenever I tried to do it, it throws an error that `module 'statistics' has no attribute 'quantiles'`.

[image]

Comment: [`statistics.quantiles`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.quantiles) was added in version 3.8. What version do you use?

Comment: I am using 3.7.6 , so that's might be the reason I am getting this error.

Comment: FYI according to the [mre] page you should never post images of code/errors here, just paste the text into the question.

Comment: @Avicii That's *certainly* the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using version `3.7.6` but that feature was [introduced in `3.8`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.quantiles).